# Problems in understanding the notion of "active" diffeomorphisms on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have been studying differential geometry recently in the hope of gaining a deeper understanding of General Relativity (GR).
I have run into an issue when trying to understand the notion of what is sometimes referred to (especially by physicists) as an *active* diffeomorphism, in particular, from the manifold to itself. By this I mean some diffeomorphism $\phi: M\rightarrow M$.
I've read that unlike a so-called *passive* diffeomorphism, in which one represents a given point $p\in M$ in two different sets of coordinates $\lbrace x^{\mu}\rbrace$ and $\lbrace y^{\nu}\rbrace$ related by some diffeomorphism $\phi$, an active diffeomorphism maps a given point $p\in M$ to another point $p'\in M$ such that $p'=\phi (p)$, but both points are represented in the same coordinate frame.
I'm unsure about this last point?! Is it just that because the diffeomorphism is defined without any specified geometry, and as such it preserves the structure of the manifold, hence the coordinate charts that represent it are unchanged? Obviously, if one introduces a dynamical metric $g$, then this with change under a diffeomorphism, but the coordinate charts that one can evaluate it in at each point on the manifold are unaffected. Is this correct?

Comment: It appears to me that a passive diffeomorphism is just a funny way of thinking about the identity smooth map, much like a change of basis matrix is just a funny way of thinking about the identity linear map.

Comment: To me, a passive diffeomorphism seems very similar to a transition function between overlapping coordinate charts (or is this just a particular case of a diffeomorphism?) When carrying out a passive diffeomorphism are we essentially mapping between two different sets of coordinate charts that represent the same manifold, whereas an active diffeomorphism maps between points on the manifold, but uses the same set of coordinate charts to represent those points on the manifold by?